# Sum of a special type of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a general method to derive the formula (without using mathematical induction) for the sum of the series of type $1*2+2*3+3*4+4*5+...+n(n+1)$ or perhaps $\frac{1}{(2*3*4)}+\frac{1}{(3*4*5)}+\frac{1}{(5*6*7)}+...+\frac{1}{(n*(n+1)*(n+2))}$?

I am a high school student so an elaborate explanation with example would help me best. I am looking for the formulas of those two series but I am more interested in the method of derivation of the formulas and also any general method by which such type of problems can be solved.

Comment: from where does that question come?

Comment: Are you interested in the summation in the limit up to $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @M.Alaggan Yes I would also like to know the sum of the limit upto infinity.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The question is from my school math book.

Comment: As a general approach you may be interested in the topic of [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).  Often some ingenuity is required to express terms as a difference of consecutive expressions, but verifying the right one is usually easy.

Comment: @hardmath Yes. If you can answer the question showing the method with an example it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the *rising and falling factorials* are defined  as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 n^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = n\left( {n + 1} \right)\, \cdots \;\left( {n + m - 1} \right) \\ 
 n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  = n\left( {n - 1} \right)\, \cdots \;\left( {n - \left( {m + 1} \right)} \right) \\ 
 n^{\,\underline {\, - \,m\,} }  = \frac{1}{{\left( {n + m} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } }} = \frac{1}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } }} \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
where here we consider $n$ and $m$ integers,
and that the *forward finite difference* (integer $q$) is defined as:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \Delta _{\,n} \;f(n) = f(n + 1) - f(n)\quad \quad \Delta _{\,n} ^q \;f(n) = \Delta _{\,n} \;\left( {\Delta _{\,n} ^{q - 1} \;f(n)} \right) \\ 
 \Delta _{\,n} ^{ - 1} \;f(n) = \sum\limits_{k\, = \,a}^{n - 1} {f(k)}  + c \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
then for the falling and rise factorials we have in general
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \Delta _{\,n} ^q \,n^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = m^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } \,\left( {n + q} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m - q\,} } \quad \quad \Delta _{\,n} ^q \,n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  = m^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } \,n^{\,\underline {\,m - q\,} }  \\ 
 \sum\limits_{k\, = \,1}^{n - 1} {k^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } } \quad \left| {\; - 1 \ne m} \right.\,\quad  = \frac{1}{{m + 1}}\,\left( {\left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m + 1\,} }  - 0^{\,\overline {\,m + 1\,} } } \right) = \frac{1}{{m + 1}}\,\left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m + 1\,} }  \\ 
 \sum\limits_{k\, = \,1}^{n - 1} {k^{\,\underline {\, - m\,} } } \quad \left| {\;1 \ne m} \right.\,\quad  = \sum\limits_{k\, = \,1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } }}}  = \frac{1}{{1 - m}}\,\left( {n^{\,\underline {\,1 - m\,} }  - 1^{\,\underline {\,1 - m\,} } } \right) =  \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{1 - m}}\,\left( {\frac{1}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m - 1\,} } }} - \frac{1}{{2^{\,\overline {\,m - 1\,} } }}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

In the two particular cases you indicate, then
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \sum\limits_{k\, = \,1}^n {k^{\,\overline {\,2\,} } }  = \sum\limits_{k\, = \,1}^n {k\left( {k + 1} \right)}  = \frac{1}{3}\,n^{\,\overline {\,3\,} }  \\ 
 \sum\limits_{k\, = \,1}^{n - 1} {k^{\,\underline {\, - 3\,} } }  = \sum\limits_{k\, = \,2}^n {\frac{1}{{k\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)}}}  =  \\ 
  = \frac{1}{{1 - 3}}\,\left( {\frac{1}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,2\,} } }} - \frac{1}{{2^{\,\overline {\,2} } }}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\,\left( {\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Besides the above, you may also consider the following.

The first type, can be translated into
$$
n\left( {n + 1} \right) = n^{\,\overline {\,2\,} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,2} {\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 2 \\ 
 k \\ 
 \end{array} \right]n^{\,k} } 
$$
where $n^{\,\overline {\,2\,} }$ is the *rising factorial* and ${\left[ \begin{array}{c} 2\\ k\\  \end{array} \right]x^{\,k} } $
is the unsigned Stirling N. of 1st kind.
So the whole boils down into a combination of the sum of $n$ and $n^2$,
 (and for exponents greater than $2$ will involve Bernoulli numbers).

Concerning the second, instead, it can be splitted by *partial fractions* into
$$
\frac{1}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{n + 2}}
$$
and thus solved in terms of harmonic numbers in general, while in this simple case, the sum will turn out in cancelling many of terms as pointed out by *Mariuslp* in his comment.

Comment: There' s no need to split into sums of $n$ and $n^2$; the rising factorial is much easier to sum *directly*, since $n^{\overline{3}}-(n-1)^{\overline{3}} = 3 n^{\overline{2}}$, which gives $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k^{\overline{2}} = \frac13 n^{\overline{3}}$.

Comment: For the second sum, the terms cancel out, so at the end you'll just have $\frac 12 \frac 1{n_0} + \frac 12 \frac 1{n_0+1} - \frac{1}{n_1 + 1} + \frac 12 \frac 1{n_1+2}$, assuming the sum goes from $n_0$ to $n_1$, you don't even need harmornic numbers

Comment: @HansLundmark, you are right,   falling and rising factorials have simple difference and summing  formulas, don't know why I forgot about. Thanks for remembering, I added to my post.

Comment: @Mariuslp, thanks indeed in this case you have many cancellations.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. An elaborate answer with an example would have helped me more.